# C, Open MPI: segmentation fault from call to MPI_Finalize(). Segfault does not always happen, especially with low numbers of processes

Tags: c, c99, openmpi

I am writing a simple code to learn how to define an MPI_Datatype and use it in conjunction with MPI_Gatherv. I wanted to make sure I could combine variable length, dynamically allocated arrays of structured data on a process, which seems to be working fine, up until my call to MPI_Finalize(). I have confirmed that this is where the problem starts to manifest itself by using print statements and the Eclipse PTP debugger (backend is gdb-mi). My main question is, how can I get rid of the segmentation fault?

The segfault does not occur every time I run the code. For instance, it hasn't happened for 2 or 3 processes, but tends to happen regularly when I run with about 4 or more processes.

Also, when I run this code with valgrind, the segmentation fault does not occur. However, I do get error messages from valgrind, though the output is difficult for me to understand when I use MPI functions, even with a large number of targeted suppressions. I am also concerned that if I use more suppressions, I will silence a useful error message.

I compile the normal code using these flags, so I am using the C99 standard in both cases:
        -ansi -pedantic -Wall -O2 -march=barcelona -fomit-frame-pointer -std=c99
and the debugged code with:
        -ansi -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -g

Both use the gcc 4.4 mpicc compiler, and are run on a cluster using Red Hat Linux with Open MPI v1.4.5. Please let me know if I have left out other important bits of information. Here is the code, and thanks in advance:

```
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <limits.h>

#include "mpi.h"

#define FULL_PROGRAM        1

struct CD{

    int int_ID;
    double dbl_ID;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int numprocs, myid, ERRORCODE;

#if FULL_PROGRAM
    struct CD *myData=NULL;             //Each process contributes an array of data, comprised of 'struct CD' elements
    struct CD *allData=NULL;            //root will dynamically allocate this array to store all the data from rest of the processes
    int *p_lens=NULL, *p_disp=NULL;     //p_lens stores the number of elements in each process' array, p_disp stores the displacements in bytes
    int MPI_CD_size;                    //stores the size of the MPI_Datatype that is defined to allow communication operations using 'struct CD' elements

    int mylen, total_len=0;             //mylen should be the length of each process' array
                                        //MAXlen is the maximum allowable array length
                                        //total_len will be the sum of mylen across all processes

    // ============ variables related to defining new MPI_Datatype at runtime ====================================================
    struct CD sampleCD = {.int_ID=0, .dbl_ID=0.0};
    int blocklengths[2];                //this describes how many blocks of identical data types will be in the new MPI_Datatype
    MPI_Aint offsets[2];                //this stores the offsets, in bytes(bits?), of the blocks from the 'start' of the datatype
    MPI_Datatype block_types[2];        //this stores which built-in data types the blocks are comprised of
    MPI_Datatype  myMPI_CD;             //just the name of the new datatype
    MPI_Aint myStruct_address, int_ID_address, dbl_ID_address, int_offset, dbl_offset;  //useful place holders for filling the arrays above
    // ===========================================================================================================================
#endif
    // =================== Initializing MPI functionality ============================
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    // ===============================================================================
#if FULL_PROGRAM
    // ================== This part actually formally defines the MPI datatype ===============================================
    MPI_Get_address(&sampleCD, &myStruct_address);          //starting point of struct CD
    MPI_Get_address(&sampleCD.int_ID, &int_ID_address);     //starting point of first entry in CD
    MPI_Get_address(&sampleCD.dbl_ID, &dbl_ID_address);     //starting point of second entry in CD
    int_offset = int_ID_address - myStruct_address;         //offset from start of first to start of CD
    dbl_offset = dbl_ID_address - myStruct_address;         //offset from start of second to start of CD

    blocklengths[0]=1;  blocklengths[1]=1;                  //array telling it how many blocks of identical data types there are, and the number of entries in each block
    //This says there are two blocks of identical data-types, and both blocks have only one variable in them

    offsets[0]=int_offset;  offsets[1]=dbl_offset;          //the first block starts at int_offset, the second block starts at dbl_offset (from 'myData_address'

    block_types[0]=MPI_INT; block_types[1]=MPI_DOUBLE;      //the first block contains MPI_INT, the second contains MPI_DOUBLE

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocklengths, offsets, block_types, &myMPI_CD);       //this uses the above arrays to define the MPI_Datatype...an MPI-2 function

    MPI_Type_commit(&myMPI_CD);     //this is the final step to defining/reserving the data type
    // ========================================================================================================================

    mylen   = myid*2;       //each process is told how long its array should be...I used to define that randomly but that just makes things messier

    p_lens  = (int*)        calloc((size_t)numprocs,    sizeof(int));       //allocate memory for the number of elements (p_lens) and offsets from the start of the recv buffer(d_disp)
    p_disp  = (int*)        calloc((size_t)numprocs,    sizeof(int));

    myData  = (struct CD*)  calloc((size_t)mylen,       sizeof(struct CD));         //allocate memory for each process' array
    //if mylen==0, 'a unique pointer to the heap is returned'

    if(!p_lens) {   MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   }
    if(!p_disp) {   MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   }
    if(!myData) {   MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   }


    for(double temp=0.0;temp<1e6;++temp) temp += exp(-10.0);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);                                //purely for keeping the output organized by give a delay in time

    for (int k=0; k<numprocs; ++k) {

        if(myid==k) {

            //printf("\t ID %d has %d entries: { ", myid, mylen);

            for(int i=0; i<mylen; ++i) {

                myData[i]= (struct CD) {.int_ID=myid*(i+1), .dbl_ID=myid*(i+1)};            //fills data elements with simple pattern
                //printf("%d: (%d,%lg) ", i, myData[i].int_ID, myData[i].dbl_ID);
            }
            //printf("}\n");
        }
    }

    for(double temp=0.0;temp<1e6;++temp) temp += exp(-10.0);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);                            //purely for keeping the output organized by give a delay in time

    MPI_Gather(&mylen,  1, MPI_INT, p_lens, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);     //Each process sends root the length of the vector they'll be sending

#if 1
    MPI_Type_size(myMPI_CD, &MPI_CD_size);          //gets the size of the MPI_Datatype for p_disp
#else
    MPI_CD_size = sizeof(struct CD);                //using this doesn't change things too much...
#endif

    for(int j=0;j<numprocs;++j) {

        total_len += p_lens[j];

        if (j==0)   {   p_disp[j] = 0;                                      }
        else        {   p_disp[j] = p_disp[j-1] + p_lens[j]*MPI_CD_size;    }
    }

    if (myid==0)    {

        allData = (struct CD*)  calloc((size_t)total_len,   sizeof(struct CD));     //allocate array
        if(!allData)    {   MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   }
    }

    MPI_Gatherv(myData, mylen, myMPI_CD, allData, p_lens, p_disp, myMPI_CD, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //each array sends root process their array, which is stored in 'allData'

    // ============================== OUTPUT CONFIRMING THAT COMMUNICATIONS WERE SUCCESSFUL=========================================
    if(myid==0) {

        for(int i=0;i<numprocs;++i) {
            printf("\n\tElements from %d on MASTER are: { ",i);
            for(int k=0;k<p_lens[i];++k)    {   printf("%d: (%d,%lg) ", k, (allData+p_disp[i]+k)->int_ID, (allData+p_disp[i]+k)->dbl_ID);   }

            if(p_lens[i]==0) printf("NOTHING ");
            printf("}\n");
        }
        printf("\n");       //each data element should appear as two identical numbers, counting upward by the process ID
    }
    // ==========================================================================================================

    if (p_lens) {   free(p_lens);   p_lens=NULL;    }       //adding this in didn't get rid of the MPI_Finalize seg-fault
    if (p_disp) {   free(p_disp);   p_disp=NULL;    }
    if (myData) {   free(myData);   myData=NULL;    }
    if (allData){   free(allData);  allData=NULL;   }       //the if statement ensures that processes not allocating memory for this pointer don't free anything

    for(double temp=0.0;temp<1e6;++temp) temp += exp(-10.0);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);                            //purely for keeping the output organized by give a delay in time
    printf("ID %d: I have reached the end...before MPI_Type_free!\n", myid);

    // ====================== CLEAN UP ================================================================================
    ERRORCODE = MPI_Type_free(&myMPI_CD);           //this frees the data type...not always necessary, but a good practice

    for(double temp=0.0;temp<1e6;++temp) temp += exp(-10.0);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);                                //purely for keeping the output organized by give a delay in time

    if(ERRORCODE!=MPI_SUCCESS)  {   printf("ID %d...MPI_Type_free was not successful\n", myid); MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 911); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    else                        {   printf("ID %d...MPI_Type_free was successful, entering MPI_Finalize...\n", myid);       }
#endif
    ERRORCODE=MPI_Finalize();

    for(double temp=0.0;temp<1e7;++temp) temp += exp(-10.0);        //NO MPI_Barrier AFTER MPI_Finalize!

    if(ERRORCODE!=MPI_SUCCESS)  {   printf("ID %d...MPI_Finalize was not successful\n", myid);  MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 911); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    else                        {   printf("ID %d...MPI_Finalize was successful\n", myid);      }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the valgrind messages? or perhaps one or two representative samples of the valgrind messages?

Comment: I suggest removing the casts from the `calloc(3)` calls -- you've included `<stdlib.h>`, so you've got a prototype, and casting the return values can hide warning messages.

Comment: @sarnold: before I try removing the casts you specified, I generated some valgrind output. I have attempted to post details [here](https://www.mit.edu/~sgildea/), but the only clear messages that I can understand is:`Invalid read of size 8, at [line I print gathered data on root process], Address ... is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd` There is another such message for an invalid read of size 4, referring to the same line number

Comment: @sarnold: I also ran w/o the casts from the calloc() calls. No additional warnings were issued by compiler, and result is the same. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: The casting of the arguments for calloc() is also useless. (and the array indexing is suspect.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop on k is bogus, but is not technically *wrong* -- it's just useless.

The real issue is that your displacements to MPI_GATHERV are wrong.  If you run through valgrind, you'll see something like this:

```
==28749== Invalid write of size 2
==28749==    at 0x4A086F4: memcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:838)
==28749==    by 0x4C69614: unpack_predefined_data (datatype_unpack.h:41)
==28749==    by 0x4C6B336: ompi_generic_simple_unpack (datatype_unpack.c:418)
==28749==    by 0x4C7288F: ompi_convertor_unpack (convertor.c:314)
==28749==    by 0x8B295C7: mca_pml_ob1_recv_frag_callback_match (pml_ob1_recvfrag.c:216)
==28749==    by 0x935723C: mca_btl_sm_component_progress (btl_sm_component.c:426)
==28749==    by 0x51D4F79: opal_progress (opal_progress.c:207)
==28749==    by 0x8B225CA: opal_condition_wait (condition.h:99)
==28749==    by 0x8B22718: ompi_request_wait_completion (request.h:375)
==28749==    by 0x8B231E1: mca_pml_ob1_recv (pml_ob1_irecv.c:104)
==28749==    by 0x955E7A7: mca_coll_basic_gatherv_intra (coll_basic_gatherv.c:85)
==28749==    by 0x9F7CBFA: mca_coll_sync_gatherv (coll_sync_gatherv.c:46)
==28749==  Address 0x7b1d630 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Indicating that MPI_GATHERV was given bad information somehow.

(there are other valgrind warnings that come from libltdl inside Open MPI which are unfortunately unavoidable -- it's a bug in libltdl, and another from PLPA, which is also unfortunately unavoidable because it's intentionally doing that [for reasons that aren't interesting to discuss here])

Looking at your displacements computation, I see

```
    total_len += p_lens[j];                                                              

    if (j == 0) {                                                                        
        p_disp[j] = 0;                                                                   
    } else {                                                                             
        p_disp[j] = p_disp[j - 1] + p_lens[j] * MPI_CD_size;                             
    }
```

But MPI gather displacements are in units of datatypes, not bytes.  So it really should be:

```
p_disp[j] = total_len;
total_len += p_lens[j];
```

Making this change made the MPI_GATHERV valgrind warning go away for me.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is not technically wrong, but it is an indication that in fact the OP wants something different to happen. But: good catch: the offset+length calculations were suspect.

Comment: @Jeff: I implemented your suggestion, and it now works as I had hoped. I don't understand why it gave me the right output when I was so far off - conceptually - in my use of the displacements, but I am glad to have this problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This outer on 'k' loop is just bogus. It's body is only executed for k=myid (which is a constant for every running process). The k is never referenced inside the loop (except the comparison with the almost-constant myid).
Also, the line with `mylen = myid*2;` is frowned upon. I suggest you change it to a constant.

```
 for (int k=0; k<numprocs; ++k) {

    if(myid==k) {

        //printf("\t ID %d has %d entries: { ", myid, mylen);

        for(int i=0; i<mylen; ++i) {

            myData[i]= (struct CD) {.int_ID=myid*(i+1), .dbl_ID=myid*(i+1)};            //fills data elements with simple pattern
            //printf("%d: (%d,%lg) ", i, myData[i].int_ID, myData[i].dbl_ID);
        }
        //printf("}\n");
    }
}
```

, so (given that myid is between 0 and numprocs) this whole silly construct can be reduced to:

```
for(int i=0; i<mylen; ++i) {
        myData[i].int_ID=myid*(i+1);
        myData[i].dbl_ID=myid*(i+1);  
        }
```

Comment: As I said, the 'k' variable is never used inside the loop. (except for the comparison with myid, which is always true for one particular k)

Comment: Could you help me understand what you mean by ``bogus"? I am just using it as a way to generate fake data to put into the arrays, with a simple pattern, so that I can confirm that it has been communicated properly afterward. Are you saying it is related to the segfault in MPI_Finalize(), or just that you don't like my example?...I edited b/c I misunderstood which loop you were referring to at first.

Comment: From your program, it is impossible to detect what your *intentions* are. You probably want to setup a (large) array, which each process working on it's own provate area. But I cannot destill from the source exactly *how* you want to setup things. (Note: I am new to mpi, I am just trying to read the C source)

Comment: My intention is to take variable lengths array from each process, and collect the contents on a root process to be analyzed. This toy program is intended to: (1) Generate array (arbitrary) data on each process (2)Communicate each process' array to root (3) Have root show that it received the desired message (4) exit gracefully. Eventually, I want to incorporate MPI_Gatherv using a 'custom' MPI_Datatype into a much larger program I am working with. However, I don't want to do so until I have confidence this toy program works properly. The presence of a segfault thus concerns me a great deal.

Comment: Ok, thinking back...the original reason for the 'for' loop was to print out the data in order of rank to compare with the output at the end. However, that's beside the point.

Comment: @Jeff Squyres already nailed your bug. The displacement calculations were absent or wrong.